# Who pays for sovereign ratings?

Tags: credit-ratings

Does the "issuer-pay" model hold also for sovereign credit ratings?
Do States pay for having their bond being rated?

Comment: good question .. not "too" quant but good ;)

Comment: any idea where I can find an answer?!

Comment: If this was for me: no, no idea. And my remark was not sarcastic only .. ;) it really is a good question.

Answer (score 2):

The "issuer-pay" model works like this: The Rating Agency goes to the issuer and says "We heard that you are going to issue bonds. We can give you a rating if you pay us XXX dollars. It will help you a lot to have our rating". The Issuer of course is free to refuse this offer (after all this is just a rating agency, not the Cosa Nostra). In this case the rating agency can still rate the issuer if it wants to (for a variety of reasons, for example to allow comparison with other issuers).  I believe the big countries (United Kingdom, USA, etc.) fall in the latter case: they never pay for ratings, so they are rated gratis (at no charge). In general it will depend on the country's judgement of whether they need a rating or not.

Comment: It is quite disconcerting to read the most famous italian Mafia Group here, since i'm italian and passionate crime-films watcher. But this is off topic. I think all rated countries pay for the rating, otherwise, if I don't pay for a rating but i'm rated anyway, no one will pay for a rating.

Comment: Could you provide me some paper or some relevant and reliable sources talking about this topic? Because I cannot find anything on the web, and there are a lot of people claiming for the contrary..